# How can I solve this Haskell pattern matching exercise?

Tags: list, haskell, pattern-matching

I do not really understand what I have to do in this Haskell exercise. Can anybody help me to solve it ?

It's about complex pattern matching:

Give expressions x0, x1, and x2 for which the following function `f` returns 0, 1, and 2, respectively. That is, give some definitions of x0, x1 and x2 such that f x0 == 0, f x1 == 1 and f x2 == 2.

Here is the definition of function `f`:

```
f :: [[(a, [b])]] -> Int
f [(x, xs): [y, ys]] = 0
f ([_]: [(x, [xs])]: [y, ys]: []) = 1
f ([(x, y: _: [])]: []) = 2
```

For testing purposes, one has to evaluate these 3 expressions:

```
f x0 == 0
f x1 == 1
f x2 == 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are supposed to write something like:

```
x0 = [ ... your answer here ... ]
x1 = [ ... your answer here ... ]
x2 = [ ... your answer here ... ]
putStrLn $ "f x0 = " <> show (f x0)
putStrLn $ "f x1 = " <> show (f x1)
putStrLn $ "f x2 = " <> show (f x2)
```

The point is to demonstrate that you can read the patterns in the definition of `f` that you quoted and find a value that fits.

Some hints:

- Look at the type of `f`. Each answer should be a list of lists of pairs, where each pair consists of a value and a list. So a value of the right type (but not the answer you want) could be `[[(1,[56,64,23]), (2, [78])], []]`. That is a list containing two sublists. The first has two values, the second has none.
- I've used integers in the example, but you could use any other type.
- The first problem uses `:` followed by a list with two elements. That means the answer is going to have 3 elements. And the 3 element list is going to be the only item in the outer list (list of lists, remember).

Comment: Oh, so I have to write examples for the f for example : x0= [(1,3)[10:15]] ?

Comment: Yes, that's it. (Except that the example you give is not the right answer).

Comment: Could you help me with  the first one?

Comment: Interesting exercise ! For example, the first pattern, for output zero, is like `[ pair0 : [pair1,pair2] ]` ; so it has to be a list of list, but containing a single list having 1+2 elements. Elements are any pairs of type (a,[b]) so for example `(True,[True])` is a valid element. Hence you could try: `f [ [ (True,[True]),(True,[True]),(True,[True]) ] ]`

Comment: Side remark: the *title* of your question is very important in order to allow interested users to find it. As is, the title only says “Haskell problem”. For example, you might want to have “*pattern matching*” somewhere in your title.